# AutoMapper, Call Mapper.Map() inside a custom type converter?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am currently testing with AutoMapper, but i currently have a case where the property names do not match each other, so a custom type convert was needed.
But when i use the custom type converter, i have to map all other properties manually? i can't call another Map inside the type converter ofcourse as this will cause a overflow.

This is unwanted as there are at most 3 model specific properties that do not match per model so i DO want the other properties to be automaticaly mapped.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a custom type converter to map classes where there a few properties that simply have names that don't match. Custom type converters are for when you need to, [as they say](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters), "take complete control over the conversion of one type to another".

Set up the map with `CreateMap()` and then set some extra rules using `ForMember()`, like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Customer>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Surname, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateOfBirth, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DOB));
```

This maps `LastName` and `DOB` from the source `Person` class to the `Surname` and `DateOfBirth` properties of the destination `Customer` class.

Comment: What should I do if I use custom `ITypeConverter` with complicated mapping logic and I also do not want to map properties with same names manually?

Comment: @JosephKatzman sorry, that answer is nearly seven years old and I haven't used AutoMapper for probably six years. :-) Might need to create a new question.